# Computer fails to boot - CPU Fan starts and stops with flashing yellow/red lights

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, fan, desktop-computer

[Video of cpu fan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N41Ew.jpg)

Moved houses recently to an old house.  Tried plugging in my PC and turning it on (video above) and it won't boot. No boot screen at all.  I tried removing the gpu, SSD, and tried using each ram stick individually to no avail.  Tried reseating all wires and cmos battery.  I have an aorus x570 elite wifi motherboard but can't find any info on what the CPU lights mean (if anything)

Comment: Does it start from a bootable USB Key? If so, get the hardware tests for your machine and test, particularly the SSD and motherboard/CPU to see if that exposes hardware failure.

Comment: Test the computer at a friends house to exclude any error by the electrical installation. If that doesn't work, get a motherboard speaker/beeper and check the beep codes. If it does not beep at all, replace the motherboard. It is likely that it got damaged during transport due to shocks+weight of the components.